# BigQuery table patch supported operations

Tags: google-bigquery

Does anyone know what the definitive list of operations supported by the [tables.patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch) operation? I know it supports adding columns, and it does *not* support removing columns, however I'm not sure what I can modify on a column, and if so what properties can be modified.

Comment: For now, you can only add a column or add a field to a struct type column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `patch` operation can do everything the `update` operation does. As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.tables.html#patch), both have identical request and response bodies.

The difference is basically that `update` method replaces the whole table with the data provided by you while the the `patch` method replaces only the isolated given fields. In other words, when you do an `update` operation you will take your existing table, replace some information and persist it again. When you do a patch operation, the data provided by you will be merged into the existing table for the given fields.